# Correct LESS CSS computation syntax

Tags: less

I have a variable that sets a percentage:

```
@var-a: 50%;
```

And another that is a fixed width:

```
@var-b: 100px;
```

I want to calculate @var-c as below:

```
@var-c: (@var-a * @var-b);
```

I expected 50px, but actually get 5000px. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you just want half of `@var-b` you should just have `@var-a : 0.5`, percentages are used in the context of the client page width.

Comment: @var-a is a height variable, so I would assume it needs to stay as a percentage?

Answer (score 1):

Less calculations use the numbers regardless of the units. If you know that `@var-a` will be in percentages, you could just do something like this:

```
@var-c: unit(@var-a / 100 * @var-b, px);
```

using `unit()` allows you to control the output unit.

You can also use guards in addition to do something else if `@var-a` isn't a percentage.